# simulated annealing for placement and routing

Tags: java, c++, routes, simulated-annealing

i am in need of a well documented source code of simulated annealing for placement and routing (in c++ or java). can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4):

This question covers an implementation in C#:
[looking for simulated annealing implementation in VB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127474/looking-for-simulated-annealing-implementation-in-vb/127755#127755)

This course covers simulated annealing for placement and routing:

http://www.ecs.umass.edu/ece/tessier/courses/697ff/

And is the particular topic of this homework:

http://www.ecs.umass.edu/ece/tessier/courses/697ff/pset2/hw2.pdf

If you can't go through the process of writing it yourself, you might get in contact with the department/professor that runs the course:

http://www.ecs.umass.edu/ece/tessier/rcg/

Chances are good they have something close to what you need.

-Adam

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the source code of [Drools Planner](http://www.jboss.org/drools/drools-planner) (open source, java), more specifically `SimulatedAnnealingAccepter`. It's used for placement in the nurse rostering example.